# Rendering a custom template in the content area of OrionJS admin section

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I'm using Meteor with [OrionJS](http://orionjs.org/) framework and I have a custom template I want to render in the content area of admin section after clicking a sidebar link I've added with `orion.links.add`. How should the route look like with FlowRouter? I can't figure it out. Something like this?

```
FlowRouter.route('/dashboard', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render('orionBootstrapLayout', {content: 'dashboard'});
  }
});
```